# Copy Document Set from 2010 to 2013

Tags: migration, document-set, folder, copy-and-paste

I copied a document set from a 2010 farm to a 2013 farm (using Explorer on both document libraries). On the destination document library, the document set was converted to a folder content type. I changed the content type to be a document set adding the information from source document library. All the metadata is attached to the folder, but it is still represented as a folder, and has no document set start page. What do I do to get the Document Set working as a document set and not as a folder? Create a document set at destination and just copying the file? Or is there something better to make this work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `DocumentSet.Folder.Item.ProgId` to "SharePoint.DocumentSet". Right now it will be empty. See this for more information:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-document-sets.html

**UPDATE**
Here is the sample PowerShell code. I haven't however tested it:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursite
$list = $web.Lists["YourList"]
$docSetName = "YourDocSetName"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $web.GetFolder($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/$docSetName")
if ($targetFolder.Item.ProgId -eq "")
{
    $targetFolder.Item.ProgId = "SharePoint.DocumentSet"
    $targetFolder.Item.Update()
}
```

Comment: Super! I guess it's possible to do the same with PowerShell?

Comment: Of course it should be possible.

Comment: @BennySkogberg, see my updated answer.

Comment: A good start to build on, if I need to. I'll keep you posted if I needed to change the script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Nothing happened to the folder...

Comment: The PowerShell code didn't work? Or setting ProgId to Document Set

Comment: Powershell run without error- but nothing happened to the folder in the gui...

Comment: can you try to put write-host inside the if and outside it and ouput value of ProgId